# Python transform function- dataframe order changed

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Help!

```
df = df[df.groupby('id')['metric'].transform('max')==df['metric]]
```

and now my other functions don't work. I tried

```
df.reset_index(drop = True, inplace=True)...... #nope!
```

I tried to start from the very beginning - import libraries and re-read csv's and nope!

what happened?

```
df['d_d_Mean'] = df[df.groupby('id')['drugs'].transform('max')==df['drugs']]
```

Error:

```
<ipython-input-607-85fda50bf5a4>:12: SettingWithCopyWarning:
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

See the caveats in the documentation: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy
```

Comment: Okay, this is not an error!  This just a warning.  It is warning of behavior that you probably really don't are about anyway.  The easiest way to eliminate this "warning" is to add .copy on the end of your reassignment like this:  `df['d_d_Mean'] = df[df.groupby('id')['drugs'].transform('max')==df['drugs']].copy()`

Comment: To understand more about 'SettingWithCopy' warning look at this post: https://stackoverflow.com/q/20625582/6361531

Comment: df.sort_values(by='gen_rate', ascending=False).to_csv(os.path.join('dkp.csv'))  I also used this code and all is well.  I got my max values and my csv created.  I will used the copy in the next go round.